# outputStream escrevendo um byteArray - XSS validação

Tags: java, java-ee, xss

Estou trabalhando com um software que passa por uma "Aplicação de Segurança" que indica as linhas de codigo que são potencialmente inseguras (teoricamente).

Tendo como base o código abaixo, a aplicação sinaliza a linha do `outputStream.write()` acusando de ***Improper Neutralization of Script-Related HTML Tags in a Web Page*** (Neutralização imprópria de codigo relacionado com tags html em uma página web)

```
response.addHeader("Content-Disposition","attachment; filename=" + Util.NeutralizeFileName(filename));
byte[] bytes = obj_Data.getBytes("File");
ServletOutputStream ouputStream = response.getOutputStream();
ouputStream.write(bytes, 0, bytes.length);
ouputStream.flush();
ouputStream.close();
```

Na verdade não estou escrevendo um **html** mas sim um **arquivo para download**. Além do mais, todos os dados "não confiáveis" provenientes do usuário estão sendo **validados e neutralizados** antes de serem convertidos para o array de bytes.

Então, minha pergunta é: Isso é um algum tipo de ***false warning*** (Alerta falso)? Caso não, o que posso fazer para produzir uma **validação apropriada**?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

*Sem saber o critério usado pela ferramenta é complicado especular.*

Entretanto, o código acima pode gerar problemas de segurança pois o arquivo enviado via download poderia, em tese, ter conteúdo malicioso, desde HTML até um executável com vírus que seria baixado por um usuário.

Não sei qual a inteligência da ferramenta, mas **talvez** o aviso não seja inibido se os cabeçalhos `Content-type`, `Content-transfer-encoding` e `Content-length` forem adequadamente definidos para representar o arquivo binário.

O problema é que sem os cabeçalhos, o navegador teria que "adivinhar" qual o tipo do arquivo e isso pode ser causa de alerta.

Porém, em última análise, consulte o manual ou suporte da ferramenta em questão.

Comment: Sua resposta foi bastante útil, principalmente a parte em que diz `consulte o manual ou suporte da ferramenta em questão`. O problema é que a ferramenta não entende o **contexto** em que o software está escrevendo (ou seja, ele não distingue se é um HTML ou um arquivo para download). Então não é necessariamente um **false warning** mas sim um comportamento proposital da aplicação de análise.